# Variable within a Variable in Python (3)

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x

My head is probably in the wrong place with this, but I want to put a variable within a variable.

My goal for this script is to compare current versions of clients software with current software versions that are available from the vendor. At this stage I just want to print out what's available.

I have some def's setup with:

```
def v80(program_1 = '80.24', program_2 = '80.5', program_3 = '80.16'):
    pass
def v81(program_1 = '81.16', program_2 = '81.7', program_3 = '81.14'):
    pass
def v82(program_1 = '82.15', program_2 = '82.4', program_3 = '82.9'):
    pass
def v83(program_1 = '83.01', program_2 = '83.0', program_3 = '83.1'):
    pass
```

I'm then reading all of the clients versions from a text file and doing comparisons.

One of the vars I'm generating is "program_main", currently I'm doing something like:

```
If program_main == "83":
    if program_1:
        if v83['program_1'] > float(program_1):
            print ("Update available", program_1, "-->", v83[program_1])
    if program_2:
        if v83['program_2'] > float(program_2):
            print ("Update available", program_2, "-->", v83[program_2])
if program_main == "82"
    if program_1:
        if v82['program_1'] > float(program_1):
            print ("Update available", program_1, "-->", v82[program_1])
```

etc etc

My train of though would be something like

```
if program_1:
    if v[program_main] > float(program_1):
        print('Update available", program_1, "-->", v[program_main])
```

etc etc

I'm sure there's a much better way to do this entire setup, but this is one of my first proper python scripts so I'm happy to chalk it up to noobish-ness, just wanted to know what the right way of doing what I'm trying to achieve is.

Comment: Why do you have separate functions per version in the first place?

Comment: What exactly differs between them, just the default values for the `program_x` parameters?

Comment: yeah the table I get is something like:
client_1, 80.1, 80.5, 80.6
client_2, 83.4, 83.2, 83.8
client_3, 80.4, 80.2, 80.12

etc etc

Comment: Then put those numbers in a dictionary and simply look them up. No need to use separate functions for each just to set a few default values.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm just about to head out the door (I didn't realise someone would respond so quickly). Thanks again !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your functions into a dictionary:

```
per_version = {
    '83': v83,
    '82': v82,
}
```

and simply use that to map string to function:

```
per_version[program_main]('program_1')
```

However, you may want to instead parameterise your version functions; make *one* function that takes the version as a parameter:

```
def program_check(version, program_1=None, program_2=None, program_3=None):
   # ...
```

which then looks up default values per `program_x` parameter based no the version, again from a dictionary perhaps.

Comment: I've taken that on board and have rewritten the dicts like this:

'versions = {
    'v80':[80.24,80.16,80.15,80.7],
    'v81':[81.12,81.7,81.4,81.11],
    'v82':[82.7,82.5,82.9,82.6],
    'v83':[83.0,83.1,83.1,83.0]
    }

client = {
    'client_1':[80.1,80.1,80.1,80.1],
    'client_2':[81.1,80.1,80.1,80.1],
    'client_3':[82.1,80.1,80.1,80.1],
    'client_4':[81.1," ",80.1,80.1],
    'client_5':[80.1," "," "," "]
    }'

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out the formatting but hopefully you get it.

Everytime I think I'm onto figuring out how to compare key values between dicts I keep hitting a wall, if you can lead me in the right direction that'd be awesome !

Comment: @FenixSyd: sorry, I have *no idea* what you are trying to do there. Perhaps you need to post a new question?

Comment: Can't thank you enough, yep posted another question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635153/compare-integer-values-between-two-dictionaries-in-python