# Compare integer values between two dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, compare

My goal for this script is to compare current versions of clients software with current software versions that are available from the vendor. At this stage I just want to print out what's available.

I have two dictionaries setup:

```
versions = {
    'v80':[80.24,80.16,80.15,80.7],
    'v81':[81.12,81.7,81.4,81.11],
    'v82':[82.7,82.5,82.9,82.6],
    'v83':[83.0,83.1,83.1,83.0]
}
     
client = {
    'client_1':[80.1,80.1,80.1,80.1],
    'client_2':[81.1,80.1,80.1,80.1],
    'client_3':[82.1,80.1,80.1,80.1],
    'client_4':[81.1," ",80.1,80.1],
    'client_5':[80.1," "," "," "]
}
```

Versions = What's available / Client = Versions that clients are running

There are 4 key values representing 4 different applications and the version they're on.

I've tried a few methods but I've hit a wall with it.

I want to compare the key values in `client_[n]` against the corresponding version (not sure how to link `client_3` with `v83`, `client1` with `v80` etc). The comparison would just be along the lines of:

```
if client['client_1'][0] < versions['v80'][0]
    print(client.client_1[0],"-->",versions.v80[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following for loop:

```
>>> for i in range(len(versions)):
...     for j in range(len(versions['v8'+str(i)])):
...         try:
...             if client['client_' + str(i+1)][j] < versions['v8' + str(i)][j]:
...                 print ("client_" + str(i+1), "Program_" + str(j+1), client["client_" + str(i+1)][j],"-->",versions["v8"+str(i)][j])
...         except TypeError:
...             print ("client_" + str(i+1), "Program_" + str(j+1), "Missing")
...             continue
... 
client_1 Program_1 80.1 --> 80.24
client_1 Program_2 80.1 --> 80.16
client_1 Program_3 80.1 --> 80.15
client_1 Program_4 80.1 --> 80.7
client_2 Program_1 81.1 --> 81.12
client_2 Program_2 80.1 --> 81.7
client_2 Program_3 80.1 --> 81.4
client_2 Program_4 80.1 --> 81.11
client_3 Program_1 82.1 --> 82.7
client_3 Program_2 80.1 --> 82.5
client_3 Program_3 80.1 --> 82.9
client_3 Program_4 80.1 --> 82.6
client_4 Program_1 81.1 --> 83.0
client_4 Program_2 Missing
client_4 Program_3 80.1 --> 83.1
client_4 Program_4 80.1 --> 83.0
```

However, this relies on the information you have provided being consistent, the number of `versions` and `clients` being the same, with the same length lists.

If you were a bit more clear, I could try for a more robust solution.

Comment: This seems to be pretty perfect, the only thing it's functionally not doing is taking into account when a client is not running a program (represented by a blank). In my original code I had something like an "if clinet['client_4'][2]:" to just check and see if the value is there.

Comment: Also, it's going to take me about 30-60 minutes to unhinge your code and fully understand how it works... good stuff but I'll need a while to keep up :)

Comment: I amended it to handle the empty strings

Comment: Sorry I'm just on my iPad now because I'm out the door and want to catch you while you're still around...... The absolute desired output would be (Client_1 program_1 80.1 --> 80.24), (Client_1 program_2 80.1 --> 80.16) and so on. In my original iteration I had named those key values program_1, program_2 etc but they're not at the moment. Can I label them in the dict?

Comment: Omg I feel like a massive jerk, great solution for the program_1 naming except I actually need to name them the program names... I'm just keeping them generically named for here. You've already gone above an d beyond my request, kudos to you sir !

Comment: as in `v80_1, v80_2` etc?

Comment: Nah let's say v80 Pepsi, v80 coke, v80 sprite, v80 dr pepper and then v81 Pepsi etc etc etc

Comment: Oh well I cant add those because I don't know that they are, but just substitute them in for the word program. please see here if this answer was helpful http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a third dictionary that acts as an interface

```
versions = {
'v80':[80.24,80.16,80.15,80.7],
'v81':[81.12,81.7,81.4,81.11],
'v82':[82.7,82.5,82.9,82.6],
'v83':[83.0,83.1,83.1,83.0]
}

interface = {

"client_1":"v80",
"client_2":"v81",
"client_3":"v82",
"client_4":"v83",
"client_5":"v84"
}

client = {
'client_1':[80.1,80.1,80.1,80.1],
'client_2':[81.1,80.1,80.1,80.1],
'client_3':[82.1,80.1,80.1,80.1],
'client_4':[81.1," ",80.1,80.1],
'client_5':[80.1," "," "," "]
}
```

Now just use the following to compare:

```
if client['client_1'][0] < versions[interface["client_1"]][0]:
    print client["client_1"][0],"-->",versions[interface["client_1"]][0]
```

Comment: This does look like a good idea but I couldn't get it working :(

Have a look at user3636636's solution, that seems to be doing the trick without the extra table.

Comment: If you are using Python 3+, include () for print statements. Is that is why it doesn't work?

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
if client['client_1'][0] < versions['v80'][0]:
    print(client["client_1"][0] ,"-->",versions["v80"][0])
```

To do it for all client and versions:

```
versions = {
'v80':[80.24,80.16,80.15,80.7],
'v81':[81.12,81.7,81.4,81.11],
'v82':[82.7,82.5,82.9,82.6],
'v83':[83.0,83.1,83.1,83.0]
}

client = {
'client_1':[80.1,80.1,80.1,80.1],
'client_2':[81.1,80.1,80.1,80.1],
'client_3':[82.1,80.1,80.1,80.1],
'client_4':[81.1," ",80.1,80.1],
'client_5':[80.1," "," "," "]
}


for cli, num_cl in client.items():
    for ver, num in versions.items():
        if int(num[0]) == int(num_cl[0]):
            print(cli, num_cl, ver, num)
```

And the output:

```
client_4 [81.1, ' ', 80.1, 80.1] v81 [81.12, 81.7, 81.4, 81.11]
client_5 [80.1, ' ', ' ', ' '] v80 [80.24, 80.16, 80.15, 80.7]
client_2 [81.1, 80.1, 80.1, 80.1] v81 [81.12, 81.7, 81.4, 81.11]
client_3 [82.1, 80.1, 80.1, 80.1] v82 [82.7, 82.5, 82.9, 82.6]
client_1 [80.1, 80.1, 80.1, 80.1] v80 [80.24, 80.16, 80.15, 80.7]
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I need a more automated way. Right now I have about 20 clients all on different versions. If I set it up this way it would be a bunch of repeated code which would have to be maintained everytime a client changed a "Major" version. I'd need to go through and update from comparing to v80 to v81. But yes, that works a treat :)